Coordination number of iron in ferrocene
Is coordination number of Iron in ferrocene 6 or 10?
6 because, there are 3 coordinate bonds from each cyclopentadienyl ring. And 10 because π-electron density is shared with 5 carbon atoms in each ring.
I don't know which reasoning is correct.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139389/coordination-number-in-%cf%80-complexes

Coordination number is pretty much the total number of electron pairs shared with the metal. Here there are 6 pairs of electrons shared which makes the CN 6

"Coordination number" is often not a useful idea when describing bonding in sandwich compounds.
The problem is that coordination number is only well defined for simpler compounds. So hexacyanoferrate is 6-coordinate unambiguously because it has 6 ligand and 6 bonds surrounding the iron atom. But ferrocene has two cylopentadienyl ligands in a sandwich. But all the bond lengths between the ring carbons and the iron are the same. If we count ligands, you could make a case for ferrocene having a coordination number of 2; if you count the carbon atoms in the ring, you could make a case for 10; if you count electrons (and want to compare to other iron(II) complexes), you might argue for 6.
None of this helps much in either comparing bonding or counting electrons.
Organometallic chemists tend to stick to the less ambiguous hapticity (describing ferrocene as Bis(η5-cyclopentadienyl)iron where the η5 describes how many of the carbons in the ring contribute to the bonding to the iron atom.
Coordination number isn't very helpful here. In simpler complexes with monodentate ligands, coordination number can help understand the bonding and can help count electrons. But a serious grasp of the real structure of the bonding needs molecular orbital (MO) theory as simpler models of bonding just don't cut it as a way of explaining the observed structure of the molecule. Defining a specific coordination number is pretty much irrelevant when one you start explaining the structure with MO.
Hence, deciding the coordination number in ferrocene is irrelevant and unhelpful.

And then there are clathrates, to make coordination number even more irrelevant...
